# Partial diffeq from generating function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, generating-functions

I have a two-variable recurrence relation which was given to me, and I've been playing around with it. I am familiar with the method of generating functions, but not so much with differential equations. This was one representation that I derived, and while I believe I have something else in one variable that may be more promising, I was wondering if this was a known form:

$$Q(x,y) = x^2\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x} Q(x,y)\right] +xy \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial y}Q(x,y)\right] + x^2y\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x} Q(x,y)\right]$$

I have no experience in PDE's, so I have no grounds for anticipating this to be intractable v. well-known.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a problem for the Method of Characteristics. There is good documentation on Wikipedia and elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Method of Characteristics - Lagrange-Charpit Equations.
You need to solve these differential equations:

$$\dfrac {dx}{x^2(1+y)}=\dfrac  {dy}{xy} =\dfrac {dQ}{1}$$
The first differential equation is separable:
$$\dfrac {dx}{x^2(1+y)}=\dfrac  {dy}{xy} $$
$$\int \dfrac {dx}{x}=\int \dfrac  {1+y}{y} dy $$
$$\ln x= \ln y +y +k$$
$$x=C_1ye^y \implies C_1=\dfrac {x}{ye^y}$$
Now solve the second DE:
$$\dfrac  {dy}{xy} =\dfrac {dQ}{1}$$
$$\int \dfrac  {dy}{y^2e^y} =C_1Q$$
This is not easy to integrate.

Comment: The second integral does have an expression in terms of the exponential integral Ei:
$$\int \frac{dy}{y^2 e^y} = -\operatorname{Ei}(-y)-\frac{1}{y}e^{-y}+C_2$$

Comment: Thank you @Semiclassical